# Why was MyISAM a fix to this problem caused by InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I was experiencing a very weird bug in my Python on MySQL app. The following code was in a loop that was called many times. The code never raised an error, but also never inserted any data:

```
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO test_1 (value) VALUES (10000);
    """)
```

Another strange symptom was that inserting data into the same table using phpMyAdmin later on produced very large auto_increment IDs, so the auto_increment counter was being incremented even though no data was actually in the table (according to SELECT * FROM test_1 anyway). Insertions worked fine using MySQL Workbench.

In the end I randomly discovered that using the MyISAM engine on the table instead of InnoDB fixed it. Why?

Comment: At a guess, you were leaking transactions, which were eventually rolled back, whereas MyISAM doesn't support transactions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably because you never called `commit`. MySQLdb (I suppose that's the module you're using) [automatically starts a transaction](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away) for every connection you make to your database server. All the insert queries work just fine and increment the `auto_increment`counter, but you never see the results from `phpMyAdmin` because InnoDB isolates its connection from the changes made via python. If your Python script disconnects and no `commit` call was made, the transaction is rolled back and no changes (apart from the incremented `auto_increment` counter) are persisted. See if a `db.commit()` (assuming `db` is the connection object) helps.

Also see [PEP 249 on database access in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: Another factor I didn't think of when posting the question: It was actually the first time I had an INSERT statement anywhere in the application. That should have been a clue.